# What does "Illegal use of type 'void' in signature" mean?

Tags: .net, peverify

I have a compiler that's producing an assembly. When I load the assembly and try to run a method on an object whose class is in that assembly, it throws an exception:

> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

As error messages go, this is only exactly as informative as `UR COMPILER SUXX0RZ LOLOLOL!!!`  Looking it up on MSDN says the same thing: there's something wrong with the compiler.

So I tried running PEVerify on the generated assembly and got a *slightly* more useful message:

> [MD]: Error: Illegal use of type 'void' in signature. [token:0x11000002]

Unfortunately, it doesn't say anything beyond that, such as *what signature has an illegal void*.  You know, the kind of stuff that's useful for tracking down reported errors...

Opening it up in ILDASM, I don't see any obviously wrong void-ness hanging around, so what's the next step?  Where do I go from here to figure out what my compiler is doing wrong?

Comment: Publish invalid dll somewhere for us to see? Until that my wild guess would be that you use void as function input parameter type somewhere.

Comment: @PetSerAl: That worked, and I was able to locate the problem.  Post that an an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `/TOKENS` parameter to IL DASM. That make IL DASM to show token's values as comments. Given token's value from PEVerify error message, you can easily locate problem element of assembly.